API Token not working in Delinea Secret Server
I am having an issue with API tokens in Delinea Secret Server.
I have a domain user that has access to most secrets.
As this user I can get all secrets using credentials.
So in powershell I can do this:
# Create creds object using username and password
$SScreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$SSsecurePwd)

$secretID = 138

$apiURL = “https://ssaddress/ss/winauthwebservices/api/v1/secrets/$SecretId”
$secret = Invoke-RestMethod $apiURL -credential $SScreds

Now … I want to do it with a token, I want to do it with curl from a linux box. But lets try it first with Powershell.
$tokenRoute = https://ssaddress/ss/oauth2/token
    $creds = @{
        username = $username
        password = $password
        grant_type = "password"
    }


$TokResponse = Invoke-RestMethod $tokenRoute -Method Post -Body $creds
$token = $TokResponse.access_token

$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer $token")

And this gets a token and creates a header. The header looks like this:
Key           Value
---           -----
Authorization Bearer AgJzT9yIzwYeO6GDUJEOEnQXk0yHb5X3pKIBQFVod1W30JHVCAjllIr0uU_PH6wXHkw…

Next, I try to get the secret:
$apiURL = “https://ssaddress/ss/winauthwebservices/api/v1/secrets/$SecretId”

$secret = Invoke-RestMethod $apiURL -Headers $headers

And it fails with:
  "errorCode": "API_UserDoesNotHaveViewSecretPermission",
  "message": "The user does not have view secret permission."

I tried the same with curl in Linux and using Postman.
The token is created using the user's name and password. This account has access to the secrets so why is this token not working?
In Secret Server when I look at sharing on a secret, I see the account has View and even Owner persmissions.
Am I missing a setting somewhere in Secret Server to allow tokens to be used to read secrets?
And this is what I do in bash on the linux box.
First get the access_token
token=$(curl   --request GET --location https://ssaddress/ss/oauth2/token \
--header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
--data-urlencode "username=$user" \
--data-urlencode "password=$pass" \
--data-urlencode "grant_type=password")

The access_token looks like this:
{"access_token":"AgKPftIJXzzzzzzzzzdML9ixefDlto","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":1201}

Then trim the token to get rid of the leading and trailing information ..
sstoken=`echo $token | cut -f 1 -d, | cut -f 2 -d : | sed 's/"//g'`

Then try to get the secret
curl --location --request GET https://ssaddress/ss/winauthwebservices/api/v1/secrets/128 --header "Authorization: Bearer $sstoken"

And that fails.
{
  "errorCode": "API_UserDoesNotHaveViewSecretPermission",
  "message": "The user does not have view secret permission."
}


Solved!
the URL is incorrect:
 $apiURL = “https://ssaddress/ss/winauthwebservices/api/v1/secrets/$SecretId”

it should be:
$apiURL = “https://ssaddress/ss/api/v1/secrets/$SecretId”


Please, try to avoid enclosing strings with smart quotes, see also: quoting rules
